# How to multiplex 22 analog signals

Tags: analog, integrated-circuit, multiplexer

I have 22 analog signals, is there a 22 or 24 channel multiplexer Integrated Circuit (IC)?

Comment: Most likely there is. If you are asking which chip you should buy, there's at least two problems. You haven't said any info what kind of analog signals you have (are they 1 megavolt and 10 gigahertz signals or something else), and it's off topic.

Comment: Maybe yes. But if speed and signal level are acceptable then 4 x CD4051 will work. 3 are used as 3 x 8 = 24 inputs and 3 outputs and the 4th acts to mux the 3 outputs.  The 8 lower address lines are shared by the 3 x 8 mux and the final 4051 uses 2 address lines to select the 3 outputs (plus a spare "off" channel.). | NO extra decoding is required - you need just the 4 IC and a 5 bit address.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon thank you my signals are of low to none frequency and 0-5v so your setup should. that's actually a great idea, have used this before?

Comment: Are the signals single-ended and, what is the source of these signals? What does the multiplexer feed its output to?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that it's not a free design house, homework-answering service or on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your work and findings so far in considerable detail with a schematic. The schematic tool here is easy to use. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a very warm welcome.

Comment: @Russell McMahon i have setup the 4 mux´s as you mentioned, don´t quite get you when you say "The 8 lower address lines are shared by the 3 x 8 mux and the final 4051 uses 2 address lines to select the 3 outputs (plus a spare "off" channel.)"
I´m thikering how to wire it, if you could elaborate a bit more on how to connect them many thx in advance

Comment: @CaeMostajo That should read "The 3 lower address lines are shared by the 3 x 8 mux. 
eg 8 4051s each have all A0's commoned, all A1's commoned. All A2's commoned. ied. | They now all select 1 of 8 as A0-A2 || The a 4th 4051 receives Out1 Out2 Out3 from the 3 x 8 muxes and it is addressed with A3 A4 connected via it's A0 A1. are valu

Comment: Figure 25 page 14 in [CD5051 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4051b.pdf?ts=1588739120016) - Rather that have two stages of mux they combine all outputs and use a CD4556 digital address selector to decode the 2 high address bits. This is similar but slightly superior to the above method  as there is only one analog path in each channel.

Comment: it all makes sense now =) i got it completely, thank you Russ!

Answer (score 2):

This diagram from Figure 25 page 14 in this [CD4051 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4051b.pdf?ts=1588739120016) meets your need.

Rather that have two stages of mux I mentioned in my comments they combine the 3 analog outputs from 3 x CD4051 and use a CD4556 digital address selector to decode the 2 high address bits. This is similar but slightly superior to method of using 4 x CD4051 with the 4th as a 2nd stage multiplexer as there is now only one analog path in each channel.

Each of the 3 x CD4051 has 8 inpendent analog inputs.

The CD4051 comes from the dawn of time. It's surprisingly capable for tasks that it suits :-). 30 nS typical response time, 500 Ohms typical on resistance at 5V.
Newer higher performance ICs with similar functionality are available.

[image]